# show two images with same dropdown menu from c# to html

Tags: c#, html, image, canvas

I have a c# script that creates in two for loops two sets of charts, these have the same name but are saved in two different folders in the same directory as the script, then it generates an html file in which I added a dropdown menu and once one name is selected it show the image, now my problem is that I want both the images to be showed at the same time but as a noob I could only think of creating two dropdown menu, one for the first set and one for the second.
is there a way to make it so that one it got the name can load both?

```
 string employeeImage = "";
        //the for loop that creates the charts and updates the list of the first images 
            employeeImage = employeeImage + "      <option value=\"EmployeeChargeable\\"+Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text)+".png\">"+titolo+"</option>";
        //end of the first loop

string employeeImageN = "";

        //the for loop that creates the charts and updates the list of the second images 
            employeeImageN = employeeImageN + "      <option value=\"EmployeeNonChargeable\\" + Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text) + ".png\">" + titolo + "</option>";
//end of the second looop
```

in the example two list is created with the two different paths for the mages, as of now this is then the code to create the HTML

```
string savHtml = "<html>" +
                    "<head>" +
                    "  <title>Select Image</title>" +
                    "  <script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
                    "  function displayImage(elem) {" +
                    "    var image = document.getElementById(\"canvas\");" +
                    "    image.src = elem.value;        " +
                    "  }" +
                     "  function displayImageN(elem) {" +
                    "    var imageN = document.getElementById(\"canvasN\");" +
                    "    imageN.src = elem.value;        " +
                    "  }" +
                    "  </script>" +
                    "</head>" +
                    "<body>" +
                    "  <form name=\"controls\">" +
                    //seleziona persone
                    "    <select name=\"imageList\" onchange=\"displayImage(this);\">" +
                   employeeImage+
                    "</select>" +

                    "    <img id=\"canvas\" src=\"EmployeeChargeable/fire1.png\" />" +
                     "    <select name=\"imageList\" onchange=\"displayImageN(this);\">" +
                   employeeImageN +
                    "</select>" +
                    "    <img id=\"canvasN\" src=\"EmployeeNonChargeable/fire1.png\" />" +
                    "  </form>" +
                    "</body>" +
                    "</html>";

        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\...\theFile.html", savHtml);
```

Comment: Ciao Matteo, two sets of charts > two different folders > both the images, ... can you provide a final folder structure of what you get after running your C# script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take advantage of C# literal strings, your code will be significantly more readable...

Not 100% sure about your folder structure, my sample below makes a few assumptions:

```
savHtml = @"
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Select Image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name='controls'>
        <select name='imageList' onchange='displayImage(this);'>  
            <option value='fire.png'>fire</option>
            <option value='mare.png'>mare</option>
            <option value='terra.png'>terra</option>
        </select>

        <img id='canvas' src='EmployeeChargeable/fire1.png' />
        <img id='canvasN' src='EmployeeNonChargeable/fire1.png' />
    </form>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var image = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var imageN = document.getElementById('canvasN');

        function displayImage(elem) {
            image.src = 'EmployeeChargeable/' + elem.value;        
            imageN.src = 'EmployeeNonChargeable/' + elem.value;        
        }
    </script>
    </body>        
    </html>";
```

So I hardcoded a few options it seems the folders `EmployeeChargeable` and `EmployeeNonChargeable` are always the same and all that changes is the file name *(just a guess)*

Also, I moved the script to the bottom, scripts can block additional resources from being downloaded. By placing them at the bottom, your style, content, and media could download quicker giving the perception of improved performance. Your HTML is small now and performance is not an issue but as you get in trouble with bigger stuff that is a good practice to follow.

Inside the javascript code, I moved the `getElementById` outside the function we just need that once don't need to redo on every call to the `function displayImage` all the function does now is set the source of the images.

Comment: no the folder is different one is employeechargeable and the other is employenonchargeable, still your solution should work thanks

Comment: @MatteoSala Sorry, I made a mistake on my initial edit, corrected now...  Let me know if you have any questions about the code... If you put your project on GitHub I can take a look and collaborate there.